# Pedestrian counting algorithm

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, object-recognition

Currently I am developing a pedestrian counter project (using OpenCV+QT on Linux). My idea about the approach is:

1. Capture Frames
2. Do Background Subtraction
3. clear noises (erode, dilate)
4. find blobs (cvBlobslib) - foreground objects
5. For each blob, set ROI and search for pedestrians (LBP with detectMultiScale) in these blobs (for better performance)
6. For each found pedestrian do a nested upper body search(Not sure) (better reliability)
7. If same pedestrian is found on continuing frames (3-4 frames maybe) - add that area to camshift and track - mark as pedestrian
8. Exclude camshift tracked areas from blob detection for next frames
9. If a pedestrian crosses a line increment number

I want to check if I am on the right track. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve my approach? If somebody worked on something similar, I would appreciate any useful tips, resources (and criticisms) on this problem.

Comment: You might want to rephrase you question, and leave out the OpenCV parts. Phrase it more like the conceptual question it really is (Algorithm for pedestrian counting and tracking).

Comment: Your approach sounds reasonable, have you searched for relevant academic literature? That should give you an idea of the state of the art. Background subtraction can be tricky, environmental effects as well as shadows can be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see a number of possible problems with this approach. I speak from my own experience here from improving a pedestrian counting system with a very similar approach, so I don't mean to be discouraging. On the contrary, I'd like to warn you of possible hurdles you may have to overcome in order to build an accurate and robust system.

Firstly, **background substraction** assumes that objects of interest will always be moving, and objects you aren't interested in counting will remain completely still. Surely enough, this may be the case in your scenario, but it still is a very limiting assumption. I've also found background substraction to be very sensitive to changes in illumination (I agree with geometrikal).

Be wary of making **the assumption that one blob = one person**, even if you think that your environment is well controlled. It happened way too often that blobs corresponding to people went undetected because they weren't moving or they were too small, so they were deleted by erosion or by some thresholding criteria (and believe me, you don't want to get into the "tune thresholds until everything works" trap. It doesn't work ;) ). It can also happen that a single blob corresponds to two people walking together, or a single person carrying some sort of luggage. Or a dog. So don't make clever assumptions about blobs.

Fortunately, since you do mention that you are using LBP's for **person detection**, I think you are in the right track of not making the mistakes in the paragraph above. I can't comment on the effectiveness of LBP's in particular, though. I've also read that HOG (histogram of gradients) are a state of the art method in people detection, see [Histograms of Oriented Gradients for Human Detection](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf).

My last gripe is related with using **Camshift**. It is based in color histograms, so, by itself, it works nicely when tracking a single object that is easy to distinguish by color, as long as the tracking window is big enough and there are no occlusions or abrupt changes. But as soon as you have to track multiple targets which may have very similar color descriptions and which *will* move very near to one another, you simply can't do without an algorithm that somehow allows you to maintain multiple hypothesis. This may be a particle filter or a framework such as MCMCDA (Markov Chain Monte Carlo Data Association, see [Markov Chain Monte Carlo Data Association for Multiple-Target Tracking](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~russell/papers/tr-mcmcda.pdf)). My experience with using Meanshift alone when tracking multiple objects is everything that shouldn't happen with tracking: losing track, confusing targets, fixating in the background, etc. Read a bit about multiple object tracking and data association problems, this might be at the heart of counting multiple people after all (I say "might be" because your goal is counting not tracking, so I don't completely discard the possibility of some clever approach that counts without tracking...)

My last piece of advice is: **there is only so much you can do with a given approach**, and you *will* need fancier stuff to achieve better performance (so I disagree with user36624 in this regard). This may imply changing a piece of your algorithm by something more powerful, or changing the architecture altogether. Of course, you have to know which fancy stuff is really useful for you. There are publications that attempt to solve the problem in a principled way, while others simply come up with an algorithm for a given data set and expect you to train a classifier that isn't really suited to the problem at hand, while requiring you to adjust a few thresholds too. People counting *is* ongoing research, so don't expect things to come easily. Do make an effort to learn things that are slightly beyond your ability, and then do it again and again...

I acknowledge that I haven't offered any solutions and instead have only pointed out flaws in your approach (which all come from my own experience). For inspiration, I recommend you read some recent research, for example [Stable Multi-Target Tracking in Real-Time Surveillance Video](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~lav/Papers/benfold_reid_cvpr2011/benfold_reid_cvpr2011.html). Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

I think what you are asking is about the feasibility of your pedestrian algorithm.

There are two general strategies for this kind of problems:

1. (bottom-to-top) Consider it as a pure detection problem, where in
   each frame you detect only pedestrians. Once you detect them, a)
   counting their number in a frame is fairly easy; and b) tracking any
   of them in consecutive frames is also easy. Therefore, you solve everything.
2. (top-to-bottom) Consider it as a action recognition problem, where you detect whether a ROI in consecutive frames is a pedestrian or not according its actions. Once you solve this problem, then you solve the detection and tracking problems simultaneously.

Your heuristic algorithm is in the first category. I donot want to discourage you, but you might miss the key point that **how to detect a pedestrian**. Because real data can be more complicated than what you thought. For example, if this is a subway camera, whose frames maybe full of pedestrians and thus removing background or detecting blobs does not help at all. In this case, it maybe more reasonable to use face detection and face recognition algorithms to solve the problem, because if you find a face you find a pedestrian. On the other hand, depending on your definition of a pedestrian, it maybe true that not everyone appeared in a frame should be treated as a pedestrian. In this case, it might be reasonable to use action recognition algorithms (the second category), where you can explicitly define a pedestrian based on his or her behaviors.

Here are some tips based on my experience:

1. Stick on what you know and what you can easily pick up. Donot invest
   your time on something is fancy but requiring many backgrounds you
   donot have. Trust me, all these algorithms will be good in some case
   but bad in some others. Therefore, the first thing is to make
   something work, no matter how good or bad it is.
2. Know more about your data and then determine your method. A general description about a problem is insufficient in many cases.
3. If you want to demonstrate your idea,  it is better to use MATLAB and build a prototype.